# Despite having check getting Integrity constraint violation error

Tags: php, laravel

I'm on laravel 5.2 and I'm checking whether the combo of 3 ids exists or not in DB after that I'm updating or creating the record.
  I have the unique key index on `first_id, second_id, third_id field`. Still, occasionally  I'm getting: `Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '103797-5371-D8BTmX0GAi' for key 'first_id'.`

```
  public function notification($fId, $sId, $tId)
  {
    $getEmail = Input::get('email');
    $email = new Email($getEmail);

    if(!$email->isValid()){
      return Response::json(['error_message' => self::ERROR_MESSAGE_INVALID_EMAIL], 422);
    }

    $searchEmail = DB::table('newsletter')
      ->select('id', 'status', 'email')
      ->where(['first_id' => $fId, 'second_id' => $sId, 'third_id' => $tId])
      ->first();

    if($searchEmail){
      $updateEmail = DB::table('newsletter')
        ->where(['first_id' => $fId, 'second_id' => $sId, 'third_id' => $tId])
        ->update(['email' => $getEmail, 'deleted_at' => NULL, 'status' => 1, 'updated_at' => Carbon::now()]);
      if($updateEmail){
        return Response::json('Success',201);
      }
    }else{
      $result = DB::table('newsletter')
        ->insertGetId(['email' => $getEmail, 'first_id' => $fId, 'second_id' => $sId, 'third_id' => $tId]);
      if($result){
        return Response::json('Success',201);
      }
    }
  }
```

We have huge traffic and we get an error like this 5-6 times a week. Despite we have a check for record exists or not.
  Is that can be DB sync issue? or is it something wrong with the code?

Comment: unique index the three of them at once or for each one ??

Comment: @Maraboc Three of them at once.

Comment: can you add the code of the index because i think laravel check it for each of them

Comment: I have added that constraints in a DB itself.

Comment: I'm googling for this and maybe it looks like a issue of race condition. But not sure about that or what will be the better fix for that

Comment: Laravel provides the https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#pessimistic-locking. Not sure how it can be used here